# Why couldn't Harry frighten Ginny?

Tags: harry-potter

About Harry Potter's personality and traits, wiki canon states:

> Harry also had shown signs of suffering from recurring clinical depression, such as his sullen and withdrawn demeanor during his mid-to-late teens as a result of the tragedies in his life. **A particular symptom of this was his outrageous temper during his bouts of depression, which frightened all but Ginny** by their sheer force and magnitude alone.

About Ginevra_Weasley's personality and traits, wiki canon states:

> **Ginny was notably difficult to intimidate or frighten, as seen during her moments of standing up to Harry during his moments of rage and anger. This is particularly impressive given that Harry's rages were capable of terrifying even his best friends Ron and Hermione, who were both incredibly courageous individuals**.

As one example, in the chapter 4 of *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, while at the home of Mrs. Weasley during a wizards' meeting, Harry shouts Ron and Hermione (Rowling uses extensively CAPITAL LETTERS for Harry's words) at the lack of news. Ron with his mouth half-open, clearly stunned and at a loss, and Hermione with her eyes sparkling with tears.

Then, Ginny meets with them saying brightly:
“Oh hello, Harry!”. “I thought I heard your voice”

Ron and Hermione tell Harry what Rita has been writing about him in the Daily Prophet tabloid. Harry rages again spluttering about a now famous Voldemort for killing his parents.

“We know, Harry,” said Ginny earnestly.

Finally, Ginny grimaced at Ron and Hermione and leaves. Harry is alone with Ron and Hermione again. Both of them were watching him apprehensively, as though they feared that he would start shouting again now that everyone else had gone. The sight of them looking so nervous...

Here another example in the chapter 23 of the same book (OotP) where Hermione confronts Harry about hiding from everyone, Harry looks at them (Hermione, Ginny and Ron) angrily. Ron looked down at his feet, however, Ginny seemed quite fearless and stares him right down.

> "We wanted to talk to you, Harry," said Ginny, "but as you've been hiding ever since we got back --".
>
> "I didn't want anyone to talk to me," said Harry, who was feeling more and more nettled.
>
> "Well, that was stupid of you," said Ginny angrily, "seeing as you don't know anyone but me who's been possessed by You-Know-Who, and I can tell you how it feels."
>
> Harry remained quite still as the impact of these words hit him. Then he wheeled around.
>
> "I forgot," he said.
>
> "Lucky you," said Ginny coolly.

Comment: Could you narrow this down to a specific moment or moments? Perhaps aided by a quote?

Comment: Harry's temper is not particularly outrageous for a teenager of his age. He shouts at his friends a few times and that is about it.

Comment: He also gets into a fight or two with Draco Malfoy over Malfoy's bullying, which is a bit more severe but again, not particularly outrageous at that stage. I mean, Hermione punched Malfoy too and also attacked one of her *friends* with birds.

Comment: If you're in a room with a friend and he suddenly starts raging about something and it's totally out of character for your friend, you'd sit there with your mouth hanging open, too. It's not that Ron & Hermione were _afraid_ of Harry, they were _shocked_ by his outburst. Ginny, having not been there ("thought she heard his voice"), but wasn't there to see the outburst itself, so wasn't shocked because she didn't realize the extent of the shouting.

Comment: This Wiki description imho is bullshit... "Clinical depression"? "Outrageous temper"? Wow... that's quite a stretch from just some outbursts during book 5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Rowings books are full of inconsistencies, and her attempts to fix it with additional information later usually make it worse.

> Harry's rages were capable of terrifying even his best friends Ron and Hermione

Harry is angry at his friends because they left him alone during the summer. They didn't write anything meaningful to him. To make it worse, they hinted that they know more, but wouldn't include it in their letters. Hermione at least recognizes that they have been wrong. They are not frightened, they realize that there is no real defense for the way they behaved.

Harry is not angry at Ginny because he doesn't expect anything from Ginny, he barely knows her.

> Every bitter and resentful thought that Harry had had in the past month was pouring out of him; his frustration at the lack of news, the hurt that they had all been together without him, his fury at being followed and not told about it: All the feelings he was half-ashamed of finally burst their boundaries.
>
> ...
>
> “Harry, we’re really sorry!” said Hermione desperately, her eyes now sparkling with tears. “You’re absolutely right, Harry — I’d be furious if it was me!”
>
> (Harry calms down and talks to Ron and Hermione)
>
> (Harry talks to Fred and George)
>
> “Oh hello, Harry!” said Ron’s younger sister, Ginny, brightly. “I thought I heard your voice.” (OotP)

Immediately after his outburst, Harry talks normally to Ron and Hermione. Later Fred and George join, so you could as well ask why Fred and George are not terrified.

Ginny comes after Harry has been talking to Fred and George.

So to sum it up, Harry was angry at Ron and Hermione. They were not frightened, at least Hermione admitted that their behavior was wrong. Harry had time to calm down. Harry didn't expect anything from Ginny, so he can't be disappointed by her.

The second part also isn't about how Ginny is the only fearless one. As you write, "Hermione confronts Harry", so she is not intimidated.

Ginny seems to be able to alleviate Harry's fears about being possessed. (Whether it makes sense to compare possession by diary and Harry's scar is another topic, Dumbledore still doesn't look Harry in the eyes.)

As you can see, there is no evidence that Harry terrifies Ron or Hermione.

Answer (score 4):

This question could only be seriously answered by Rowling herself.

Me, not being Rowling, can only speculate, that Ginny is probably not easy to frighten.

I guess, being possessed by Voldemort himself and walking away from that, puts some teenager's tantrum in quite some perspective.

Also, Ginny is the tough little sister in a household with six older boys. It's safe to say, she's witnessed a few fights in her life.

Hermione on the other hand is an only child (and thus hasn't grown up with fighting siblings) and Ron, as the youngest boy in the family, who probably has been on the loosing side of many such fights.